# Why is my Jira Issue Collector integration with Angular not working?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jira, integration

I want to integrate the jira issue collector with an angular app

I have tried something like

Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

declare global {
   interface Window { ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS: any; }
 }

window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS = window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS || {};

@Component({
  selector: 'cmdb-jira-issue-collector',
  templateUrl: './jira-issue-collector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jira-issue-collector.component.scss']
})
export class JiraIssueCollectorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  submitIssue() {

    console.log('submitIssue');

    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "my-url",
      type: 'get',
      cache: true,
      dataType: 'script'
    });

    window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS =  {
      "triggerFunction": function(showCollectorDialog) {
        showCollectorDialog();
      }
    };

  }

}
```

Component.html

```
<p>jira-issue-collector works!</p>
<button id (click)="submitIssue()" id="submit">Submit Issue</button>
```

However this doesnt work.

Also tried injecting the script directly inside index.html as stated in [Ways to integrate the Jira issue collector with an Angular app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55799885/ways-to-integrate-the-jira-issue-collector-with-an-angular-app) but `i get error that window.showCollectorDialog is not a function` and `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.

I am confused . What am i missing ?

Comment: How to support multiple issue collectors on the same component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently I missed the step that we also need to set the custom trigger on in the jira issue tracker settings as mentioned https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/customize-the-jira-issue-collector/ . I somehow missed this step which took me a few hours to find out. Now everything works :-)

Comment: if you have to add multiple Issue collectors, how should one go about it? I tried the above example... works well with one issue collector, but gets confused when add a 2nd issue collecor